# Executing JavaScript in Visual Studio's WebForm

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, visual-studio-2010

So, i've created a small application just for fun, which includes a webForm embedded in a tabControl, within the windows form.

The rest of the application works ok, but whenever the website I have set as the url tries to run javascript (I am assuming it is a javascript script, and not some other script), it gives me errors. Usually object null or undefined errors.

I also know that the pagination is done by javascript and clicking the buttons for the pagination does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the `scripts` you included are in the correct `path` ?

Comment: They are not my scripts, I have not even touched the scripts. They are the scripts built into the website, also not mine, that the webBrowser in my winForm links to